# Large Deviations rate function and Cramérs Theorem

Tags: large-deviation-theory

Given $X_1,...$ of iid random variables. We know that if the moment generating function $M(\theta) < \infty, \forall \theta $ from Cramérs Theorem we get:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log \mathbb{P}(S_n \ge na) = -I(a)$ where

$I(a) = \sup_\theta(a\theta - \log M(\theta))$.

Question: What happens if $M(\theta)$ isn't finite for all values of $\theta$? Namely, is there another version of Cramérs theorem to help when calculating the rate function $I$ when this situation comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Let $\Theta$ be the set of $\theta$ such that $M(\theta)<\infty$. It is easy to check that $\Theta$ is convex, that is, an interval.  As long as $\theta$ is in the interior of $\Theta$, and solves $M'(\theta)/M(\theta)=a$, that is, the maximization problem defining $I(a)$ is solved the calculus way,  the conclusion holds for that value of $a$.  The condition that you cite, that $\Theta=\mathbb R$, is introduced for  convenience of exposition.

I'm away from my books at the moment, so I can't give a reference to this version.